# C Syntax related to fgetc() and ungetc()

Tags: c

In my code I am trying to accomplish something like this (written in pseudocode):

```
While not at EOF:
    Get line
    Write line to different file
    Skip 30 bytes
```

Currently, the best way I can think of to do this is something like this:

```
int c;
while((c = fgetc(stream)) != EOF){
     ungetc(c,stream);
     REST OF CODE
```

Is there a better way to check if I am at the EOF but still use the character that I am currently reading?

Comment: you should mean `while((c = fgetc(stream)) != EOF)`

Comment: It is very unclear what you are wanting to do with the `Skip 30 bytes`.  It seems like you are wanting to read a line `while ((c = fgetc(stream)) != '\n' && c != EOF)` and use those bytes, then `for (i = 0, i < 30 && c != EOF; i++) fgetc(stream);`  -- then repeat??

Comment: This doesn't look like a syntax question. Consider editing the title.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to call `fgetc` outside of the loop conditional:

```
int c = fgetc(stream);
while(c != EOF){
    ....
    c = fgetc(stream);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `fgetc` like this:

```
while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {
    ...
}
```

**OR**, since you want to read **lines** (as your pseudocode says), you can use [fgets](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgets.3.html):

```
char *fgets(char *s, int size, FILE *stream);
```

And you would use it as:

```
char *buffer = malloc(500);

while (fgets(buffer,500, fp)) {
    // treat line here
}
```

From the manual:

> **fgets()** reads in at most one less than size characters from stream
>          and stores them into the buffer pointed to by s.  Reading stops after
>          an EOF or a newline.  If a newline is read, it is stored into the
>          buffer.  A terminating null byte ('\0') is stored after the last
>          character in the buffer.

And the **return**:

> **fgets()** returns *s* on success, and NULL on error or when end of file
>          occurs while no characters have been read.

This means the return of the `fgets` function can be used as the condition for the `while` loop (so you don't need to do the `!= EOF`).

---

**EDIT (bonus):** As for you pseudocode of `skip 30 bytes`, you may want to take a look at the [fseek](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fseek.3.html) function manual.